# VBA IF Statements converted to Case

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, case

Hi this one of the first times I am using the case statement and it would be really helpful for someone to convert.

I had a more simplistic If statement that was working but unable to have this work likely due to my end if/else placements. Always appreciate the help!

```
Public SLA As Range
Public Data1, Data5 As Range
Public TotalT As Range

Set Data1 = Worksheets("Log").Range("N" & ActiveCell.Row)
Set Data5 = Worksheets("Log").Range("R" & ActiveCell.Row)
Set TotalT = Worksheets("Log").Range("L" & ActiveCell.Row)
Set SLA = Worksheets("Log").Range("M" & ActiveCell.Row)


Select Case Data5 And Data1
If Data1 <> "" Then
    If Data5 = "A" Or "B" Then
        If TotalT.Value <= 5 And TotalT.Value <> "" Then
            SLA.Value = "Yes"
        Else
            If TotalT.Value = 0 Then
            Else
                SLA.Value = TotalT - 5

            End If
        End If
    End If
End If

If Data1 <> "" Then
    If Data5 = "C" Or "D" Then
        If TotalT.Value <= 1 And TotalT.Value <> "" Then
            SLA.Value = "Yes"
        Else
            If TotalT.Value = 0 Then
            Else
                SLA.Value = TotalT - 1
            End If
        End If
    End If
End If

If Data1 <> "" Then
    If Data5 = "E" Or "F" Or "G" Or "H" Or "I" Or "J" Then
        If TotalT.Value <= 10 And TotalT.Value <> "" Then
            SLA.Value = "Yes"
        Else
            If TotalT.Value = 0 Then
            Else
                SLA.Value = TotalT - 10
            End If
        End If
    Else
    End If
End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You too can simplify your inner if statement.
Try this:

```vb
If Data1 <> "" Then
    Select Case Data5
        Case "A", "B"
            If TotalT.Value Between 1 And 5 Then
                SLA.Value = "Yes"
            Else
                SLA.Value = TotalT - 5
            End If
         Case "C", "D"
            If TotalT.Value Between 1 And 1 Then
                SLA.Value = "Yes"
            Else
                SLA.Value = TotalT - 1
            End If
         Case "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"
            If TotalT.Value Between 1 And 10 Then
                SLA.Value = "Yes"
            Else
                SLA.Value = TotalT - 10
            End If
        Case Else
            'TODO
    End Select
End If
```

Comment: I prefer this one due to the `Case Else` clause.

Comment: @PaichengWu should there be something other than Between in the statement? I am getting Compile error: Expect: Then or GoTo where Between is.

Comment: @Tmacjoshua Which line?

Comment: @PaichengWu all of the 3 between lines. Between specifically is highlighted

Comment: @Tmacjoshua Try use `TotalT.Value >= 1 And TotalT.Value <= 5` instead of `BETWEEN` clause

Comment: @PaichengWu Thanks when I run through the code line by line it seems to skip everything after If Data1 <> "" Then  until the last end if. Should there be a statement before that possibly. It should skip if Data1 has no value but should go through it until it finds its case otherwise. Appreciate the help

Comment: @Tmacjoshua you should check the value of `Data1`.

Comment: @PaichengWu Had Date1 instead of Data1 thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is likely the ElseIf condition is being used incorrectly.

I assume that when TotalT.Value is 0 then you don't want to do anything? turning the inequality around helps if that's the case.

Untested but hopefully cleaned:

```
If Data1 <> "" Then
    Select Case Data5
        Case "A", "B"
            If TotalT.Value <= 5 And TotalT.Value <> "" Then 
                SLA.Value = "Yes"
            ElseIf TotalT.Value <> 0 Then
                SLA.Value = TotalT - 5
            End If
        Case "C", "D"
            If TotalT.Value <= 1 And TotalT.Value <> "" Then 
                SLA.Value = "Yes"
            ElseIf TotalT.Value <> 0 Then
                SLA.Value = TotalT - 1
            End If
        Case "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"
            If TotalT.Value <= 10 And TotalT.Value <> "" Then 
                SLA.Value = "Yes"
            ElseIf TotalT.Value <> 0 Then
                SLA.Value = TotalT - 10
            End If      
    End Select
End If
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. Should I add in Then after Elseif Total.Value <> 0 I am receiving an error or this line.

Comment: Missed out some 'Then'

Comment: If totalt = 0 then SLA should be Yes. I don't think I mentioned that. That probably changes things

Comment: but in the case I am trying the TotalT is > 10 and I also tried between 1-5 but it seems to pass over saying Yes or the value